# Squid IPv6 To IPV4 mapping

Tags: ipv6, squid, ipv4

i just finished setting up my squid proxy server, i have lots of IPv6 and only two IPv4 on my interface. the way squid is working currently is to use specified IPv6 tcp_outgoing_address, but if destination host is IPv4, it will automatically use one of my two IPv4, well i don't want that, i'm trying to create http proxy which each client of mine has it's own IPv6, it's done already but if DNS don't return AAAA record it will fallback to IPv4. how can i prevent this? what is the work around? i saw few proxy providers using only IPv6 but they can open IPv4 hosts without using IPv4, How?!

Comment: Are you trying to block IPv4 traffic, or use the other IPv4 address?

Comment: i don't want to use my IPv4s, i'm just planning to provide IPv6s, the problem is i cant open IPv4 servers with outgoing IPv6, others are doing it but i don't know how

Comment: You can't reach a site on IPv4 (and not on IPv6) without an IPv4 address! Others do it with IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

On Squid 4.8 the simplest solution was to go with a `dns_v4_first on` in squid.conf. Docs are at http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/dns_v4_first/